# php session is creating two (unwanted) cookies for one variable

Tags: session, cookies

I can't reproduce this in Safari, but in Chrome and Firefox, the first login of a user (after quitting the browser, or visiting from a new location) creates two cookies, one for *"www.example.com"* and one for *"example.com"*. The effect is that, once I'm logged in and on the home page, when I click to a second logged-in page, I am logged out automatically. When I log in again, the second time, there is only one cookie for `"www.example.com"` and everything works fine; I am not logged out randomly. This is how I'm creating my session:

```
session_regenerate_id(true); // destroying the old session id and creating a new one
$_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
setcookie("id", $login, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
```

I have `session_start();` at the top of every page. The $login variable is the user ID pulled from the database after username/password check passes, and it is echoing and showing up in the cookies correctly.

I don't understand it, because it ONLY happens the first time, and so far only in Firefox and Chrome. It does not happen locally in any browser, only on the live server in those two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Set up cookies for subdomains  **.example.com**

> setcookie("id", $login, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", ".example.com",
>   "", TRUE)